# using like condition in Subsonic 2.2

Tags: c#, subsonic2.2

I need some help in using "like" condition in Subsonic 2.2

Following is my query

```
DAL.DB.Select()
    .From("tblName")
    .Where("NewFirstName")
    .Like(strFirstName)
    .Or("PrevFirstName")
    .Like(strFirstName)
    .ExecuteDataSet();
```

the result returned by above query contains records those have firstname euqal to strFirstName not like strFirstName

example: there are two records which has NewFirstName as 'joe' and 'joe J' so above query just returns record that has 'joe' as NewFirstName .

Comment: A like clause requires that addition of a percent "%" symbol, which represents a wild card.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this : `strFirstName = 'joe*'` or `strFirstName = 'joe%'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding how the LIKE operator works.

Perhaps you should [peruse the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).